# BQ - Materialised Views and ARRAY_AGG

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trialling materialised views in our BQ eventing system but have hit a roadblock.

For context:

Our source event ingest tables use streaming inserts only (append only), partitioned by event time (more or less true time but always in order WRT the entity involved in the event stream), and we extract a given entities 'latest' / most recent full state. I feel with data being append only, and history immutable, there could be benefits here but currently cannot get it to work (yet)

Alot of our base BQ code is spent determining what the 'latest' state of the entity is.  This latest entity is baked into the payloads of the most recent event ingested in that table e.g OrderAccepted then later OrderItemsDespatched events (for the same OrderId), the OrderItemsDespatched event will have the most up to date snapshot of the order (post processing an items dispatch).

Thus in BQ for BI, we need to surface the most current state of that order. e.g we need to extract the order struct from the OrderItemsDespatched event since it is the most recent event.

This could involve an analytic function:

```
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER entityId ORDER BY EventOccurredTimestamp DESC)
```

and pick row=1 - however analytic functions are not supported by MVs and is not as efficient anyway as ARRAY_AGG below

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW dataset.order_events_latest_mv
PARTITION BY EventOccurredDate
CLUSTER BY OrderId
AS 
WITH ord_events AS (
  SELECT
    oe.*,
    orderEvent.latestOrder.id AS OrderId,
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", event.eventOccurredTime) AS EventOccurredTimestamp,     
    EXTRACT(DATE FROM PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", event.eventOccurredTime)) AS EventOccurredDate,    
  FROM
    `project.dataset.order_events` oe
  ),

  ord_events_latest AS (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(
      e ORDER BY EventOccurredTimestamp DESC LIMIT 1
    )[OFFSET(0)].*
  FROM 
    ord_events e
  GROUP BY
    e.OrderId
  )

SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  ord_events_latest
```

However there is an error

```
Materialized view query contains unsupported feature.
```

Fundamentally, we could save a heck of alot of current processing and cost only processing changed data, rather then scanning all the data everytime, which given its an append only, partitioned source table, seems feasible?

The logic would be quite similar for deduping our events as well, which we do alot as well with slightly different query but using ARRAY_AGG as well.

Any advice welcome, hopefully the feature the error message mentions isnt supported is not far off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I hope it works:

```
WITH
latest_records AS
(
    SELECT entityId, SPLIT(MAX(COALESCE(EventOccurredTimestamp, '||', Col1, '||', Col2, '||', Col3)), '||') values
    FROM `project.dataset.order_events`
    GROUP BY entityId
)
SELECT 
    entityId, 
    CAST(values[offset(0)]) as timestamp) as EventOccurredTimestamp,
    values[offset(1)] as Col1, -- let's say it's string
    CAST(values[offset(2)] as bool) as Col2, -- it's bool
    CAST(values[offset(3)] as int64) as Col3 -- it's int64
FROM latest_records
```

Comment: Hi thanks!  Yes we use the ARRAY_AGG only now for this type of processing needs, its much more efficient.  I will look at what you have proposed above, thanks for taking the time to reply

Comment: For first suggestion, error is: 'Unsupported operator in materialized view: Join' - doco says you cant use a join for MWs (yet - hear its soon though)

Comment: Then I'm removing the first. Then, I'd expect the second to work.